# How to evaluate the following integral?$\int_1^2\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x+x^2+x^3}$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_1^2\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x+x^2+x^3}$$
How to evaluate the following integral? I am trying this question by simplifying the denominator.

The denominator will be $(1+x)(1+x²)$ and then I am thinking for applying partial fraction method to solve the following integral? But can't solve it, because in the numerator it is $\sqrt{x}$. This is my approach.

Comment: Try letting $u = \sqrt{x}$ and do some partial fractions after.

Comment: But how to evaluate the denominator? Because in the numerator it is sq. Root of x and in the denominator it is x and x².

Comment: What do you mean by evaluating the denominator? I'm just suggesting that substitution because doing partial fractions from there would be easier.

Comment: Ok. I have understood the way of solution. Thank you very much @ Accelerator.